# Sessions not really being destroyed?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, session-variables

I've been having a problem with the sessions not being destroyed after logout. ( Although for some reason it works perfectly in IE.....but not in any other browser (chrome, firefox, opera, or safari))

Here's the code for the login authorization

```
<?php
session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="testdatabase"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// email and password sent from form 
$enteredEmail=$_POST['email']; 
$enteredPassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$enteredEmail = stripslashes($enteredEmail);
$enteredPassword = stripslashes($enteredPassword);
$enteredEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($enteredEmail);
$enteredPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($enteredPassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$enteredEmail' and password='$enteredPassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $enteredEmail and $enteredPassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $enteredEmail, $enteredPassword and redirect to file "redirect.php"
$_SESSION['email']="email"; 
header('location:redirect.php');
}
else {
    header("location:index.php?error");
}
?>
```

It then redirects to the home page

I put this code in the header to display whether the user is logged in or not

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['email']) || $_SESSION['email'] == ''){
    include_once('loggedout.php');
}
else {
    include_once('loggedin.php');
}
?>
```

I also Include these 2 files into the top of every page :

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['email']="email" ) {
session_start();   
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
$connect_error= "Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.";
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('testdatabase') or die($connect_error);
?>
```

And Finally, this is the code for the logout page that the user goes to upon clicking logout:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Logged Out</title>
</head>
<body>
<p align="center">You have been successfuly logged out.</p>
<p align="center"><a href="home.php">Go back to homepage.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

However, after returning to the homepage, it first appears as if the user is logged out, but then a simple reload of the page logs the user back in.

I've tried so many different session destroy markups but no matter what, I get the same problem.
(yes, i'm relatively new to this whole php thing, so ANY help is greatly appreciated)
Any ideas whats going on and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without thoroughly looking through your code, you say it works in some browsers and not others. Is this a cache issue?

Comment: Well I tested on multiple computers, still only works in IE and has the problem in all other browsers. :/ @RyanKempt

Comment: @user3817799 maybe your cookies are not enabled in other browser.Try enabling it as session is also a cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, but I found the problem. 
Apparently I have to be extremely specific with my url to my logout file.

I had the logout link going to `http://domain.com/logout.php`

instead of

```
http://www.domain.com/logout.php
```

...*facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

```
// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of suggestions based upon observing your current code:

1. `session_unset();` is deprecated and should not be used with `$_SESSION` — get rid of it.
2. Use a `setcookie` handler to remove cookies set with your domain:
3. Use `session_commit()` directly after `session_destroy()`, to write session data end session.

**Code:**

```
session_start(); // init session vars

if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(),'',time()-3600); # unset session id/cookies
}

unset($_SESSION['email']); // this is the key to unsetting your session.
session_destroy(); // destroy session
session_commit();  // commit session write (optional)
```

**Code (alternative):**

```
// unset session/cookies

$cs = array_keys($_COOKIE);
for ($x=0;$x<count($cs);$x++) setcookie($cs[$x],"",time()-1);

unset($_SESSION['email']); // this is the key to unsetting your session.
session_destroy();
session_commit();
```

**Notes:**

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the
>   current session. It does not unset any of the global variables
>   associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the
>   session variables again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.
>
> If $_SESSION (or $HTTP_SESSION_VARS for PHP 4.0.6 or less) is used,
>   use unset() to unregister a session variable, i.e. unset
>   ($_SESSION['varname']);.

**Caution:**

> Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will
>   disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION
>   superglobal.